# HTTP GET with all selected ids

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a conceptual question about a REST API we're developing.

We need to have an endpoint that gets entities by ID. The IDs are coming from a selection of a user from a datagrid and could potentially be hundreds of ids whereas an id is a GUID.

Since with a GET-method the ids are sent via the query-params in the url, I fear that the url would get too long and with a restful api, a GET-request should not contain a request body...

What is the correct way to implement this? via a POST even though nothing is created?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no correct way to implement it. It's your API, you decide. Just be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to implement this?

How would you do it with a web page?

You'd start with an html form, and the html form would have input controls for specifying the identifiers - might be check boxes, might be a text control - and when the form is submitted the browser will implement its general purpose form processing instructions and copy the information from the input controls into an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` representation that is then used a the query part of a GET request.

There's no particular reason that the query-part needs to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it could be something else instead.  The trick, from a REST perspective, is communicating that representation - on the web, the media type and processing rules are described in the HTML standard; browsers know what to do because the form is described within a `text/html` document, and therefore the browsers know what processing rules to apply.

URI templates give you a somewhat more flexible language for describing URI.  You can, for example, produce a template that designates that a *list* should be encoded into the URI, and a compliant general purpose component will know to create a comma separated list of encoded values.

```
http://example.org/example?{ids}
```

becomes

```
http://example.org/example?1,2,3
```

So that gives you the ability to describe the production rules for the URI freely, although you still need a mechanism to communicate that `ids` is the identifier to use, and to express that it is a list.

With a long enough list, you risk running into [414 URI Too Long](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.12); the standards don't put any limitations of the length of a URI, but implementations may impose arbitrary limits.

In that case, you do need a request with a message body.  As of 2020-12, there is no standardized method token with safe semantics and a payload that is suitable for use here.

The usual work around, is of course POST; a way of thinking about this is that we are using POST to *create* a new resource that we can later use to GET the search results that we want.  In the case where those results are immediately available, we can send in response to the POST not only the location of the new resource, but also its current representation.

But it's ok to skip the resource creation part, and just return an uncacheable representation of "the results obtained from the action".

My understanding is that as of late 2020, the HTTP working group has adopted a new proposal for standardizing another method-token; one of the possible outcomes in this case is that we'll end up with a method with safe semantics that can include a payload.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, web server may have limitation on the maximum query string length. And the browser also has restrictions on the length of the url.

Last, I recommend you to pass the data via post. Usually, there is no problem with using post instead of querystring.